Island's "Action not allowed" when trying to unlock developer options
I'm using the Island application for the sake of isolating and cloning certain applications on my Samsung running One UI 6.1. Whenever I try to unlock developer options, I get the following error:

Action not allowed
To disable this restriction, please refer to corresponding setting in Island.


The error tells me that I should see the corresponding option in the Island application itself, but there is no any kind of option to unlock developer options.
I've been trying to contact numerous people considering the problem I'm having. The developer is not answering. Some people are telling me that the work profile shouldn't allow developer options anyway.
What do you think could be a solution?

I would try granting additional permissions to the application via adb or setedit?

When it comes to ADB commands I don't think that is going to be possible since I cannot access developer options but I could give the other command a try
